# Exposing a property of a child view model in the parent view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

my parent view model contains couple child view models and it looks like

```
public MainViewModel:ObservableObject
{
     public MainViewModel(){//initalize everything};

     private SomeViewModel childvm1;
     private AnotherViewModel childvm2;


      public SomeViewModel Childvm1
            {
                get
                {
                    return childvm1;
                }
                set
                {
                    SetField(ref childvm1, value, "Childvm1");
                }
            }

     public AnotherViewModel Childvm2
            {
                get
                {
                    return childvm2;
                }
                set
                {
                    SetField(ref childvm2, value, "Childvm2");
                }
            }

     //when this changes i want to notify childvm2 and call a function in it
     public SomeModel SelectedValueofChildvm1
            {
                get
                {
                    return Childvm1.SelectedValue;
                }
            }
}
```

how can i call a function in `childvm2` when `SelectedValueofChildvm1` changes?

Comment: How does `SelectedValueofChildvm1` change, when there is no `set`?

Comment: the set is in the childvm1, do i have to expose it here too?

Comment: Do you need to react to the change of the value, or are you just trying to make it bindable?

Comment: @CodingGorilla i need to react to its change

Comment: So then, assuming your view models implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (bad assumption), simply attach a handler to `PropertyChanged` and react when the property changed.  Will that not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the PropertyChangedEvent of the child view model, like this:

```
public SomeViewModel Childvm1
{
    get
    {
        return childvm1;
    }
    set
    {
        if (childvm1 != null) childvm1.PropertyChanged -= OnChildvm1PropertyChanged;
        SetField(ref childvm1, value, "Childvm1");
        if (childvm1 != null) childvm1.PropertyChanged += OnChildvm1PropertyChanged;
    }
}

private coid OnChildvm1PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // now update Childvm2
}
```

But be careful:

- you may have to update childvm2 also in the Childvm2 setter
- you need to make sure that childvm1 instances don't outlive MianViewModel instances, or set Childvm1 to null before giving the MainViewModel back to the garbage collector.

Comment: This is good if you expect the child view models to change, if not then my approach is a lot simpler. =)

Comment: Apparently OP expects them to change, since a public setter for the Childvm1 property is included. Also, I don't know why your solution is _a_ _lot_ simpler than this? You don't unsubscribe from the event, so you have one line less code, that is true. But in this solution, subscription and unsupscription are nicely symmetrical and with the property they belong to, which is nice as well, and less fragile IMHO.

Comment: That wasn't intended as a criticism, my point was simply that if he doesn't expect it to change then it's simpler to just wire up the handler in the constructor and you're done.  We don't see what that `SetField` does, so its entirely possible that it handles property change notifications but disallows changing specific fields (such as the child view models).

Comment: @CodingGorilla I didn't take your comment as criticism, only discussing it so we and other readers can learn. In fact, I use your approach myself whenever I have a `readonly` field (and thus no setter in the property). When the field is not readonly, I do have a setter in the property (that may be private or public) and have the code in there. And you're right about SetField, but I assume it's the boilerplate "if it changed raise the event" code inherited from ObservableObject.

Answer (score 1):

This easiest way is to use the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to listen for the property change notifications.

```
public MainViewModel:ObservableObject
{
     public MainViewModel(){
        //initalize everything
        Childvm1.PropertyChanged += (s,e) {
            if(e.PropertyName == "SelectedValue") {
               // Do what you want
            }           
        };
    };

}
```